# Docker typescript node.js can't start app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I have an index.ts, then this is my script

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "ts-node-dev ./index.ts"
  },
```

I tried to dockerize it, what should I do? do I need to add another command for npm build? or generate a .js file?

my dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /

# copy configs to /app folder
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

COPY . .

# check files list
RUN ls -a

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

I can't access localhost:3001 in my browser after I run

```
docker build -t testApp .
```

then

```
docker run -p 80:3001 testApp
```

Comment: there is proper guide of docker type script and node js : https://gist.github.com/zmts/509f224950f85f3cfe4365e2b80081d1

Comment: You are binding your host's port 80 to the 3001 of the container, so it would be available under `localhost`

Comment: @KayesFahim why you need to copy tsconfig.json?